# image.save method is not save image GDI+ error occured

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

```
 string ServerUploadFolder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + value.PhysicalFileName);
                MultipartFormDataStreamProvider streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(ServerUploadFolder);
                Image img = Image.FromFile(ServerUploadFolder);
                var bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
 using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                {
                    gfx.Clear(Color.White);
                    gfx.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);
                }
                bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
 string imagePath = value.FileUrl.Replace(Path.GetFileName(value.FileUrl), Path.GetFileName(value.FileUrl));
                bmp.Save(imagePath,img.RawFormat);
```

In this Save Method There are Problem Occured GDI+ Error .
I Have Tried Many Solutions but that is not worked.
I am rotate image with 90's degree and after it is rotate it is save in database.

Comment: Please post the error, too.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+. this error occured when save that image

Answer (score 2):

In may case the **image file already exists in system drive**, so app throws the error "A Generic error occured in GDI+".

> 1. Verify that the folder must already exist where image is to be saved.
> 2. Verify that the file must not exist in the path with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The GDI+ error you're receiving is generic and could refer to any one of a number of different issues. Try the following and see how you get on:

If your image is based on a stream, ensure that it is still open when you do the Save operation. Also, make sure permissions are correct on the destination folder, i.e. that Write permission is enabled.

Finally, here's some example code which worked for me:

```
// Path to source file
string inputPath = Server.MapPath(@"~\Content\somefile.jpg");

// Create an image from the file
using (Image img = Bitmap.FromFile(inputPath))
{
    // Rotate the image 90 degrees
    img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    // Path to destination file
    string outputPath = Server.MapPath(@"~\Content\rotated" +
        System.IO.Path.GetExtension(inputPath));
    // Delete the destination file if it already exists
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(outputPath))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(outputPath);
    }
    // Save the rotated image in the same ImageFormat as the source
    img.Save(outputPath, img.RawFormat);
}
```